# Redis - Celery Configuration over Amazon EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, redis, celery

I am developing a web application using Python, Django and MySql. I have a provision in the application where in a user can upload *.wmv and *.mov files which the system will process and convert it into *.mp4. I was using a single server architecture but as the user base is growing, video conversion consumes 90% of the memory. I am thinking of moving the video conversion / streaming server over cloud using Amazon EC2 so that the conversion takes place on a different server using Redis and Celery. I wanted to know if Redis - Celery supports multi-tier architecture. If anyone has ever successfully achieved this, please let me know the steps. It will be really helpful as I was googling this but couldn't find any supporting documentation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  There is nothing stopping Celery from working with n-tier architectures.

Comment: I wanted some configuration document etc to deploy redis and celery on n tier architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a Celery queue to process your jobs, you'll need to:

- Set up rabbitMQ. You can do that on your existing host or on an EC2 instance
- Set up Celery. The [Docs](http://celeryproject.org/) are good.
- Set up redis for whatever you need it for. Again, the docs are good
- Configure your existing server to be able to talk to the task queue and redis. Basically, tweak EC2 firewall rules
- Make sure the worker server(s) can see the files. Upload them to S3 is probably the easiest way to shift them back/forth from the cloud
- Change your webserver code to trigger a celery task to do the conversion
- Figure out what to do when the conversion finishes - how do you let the user know it's done?
- Go.

Don't worry about "n-tier" etc etc - this is a simple setup that you can get going in a day by following the docs.

Comment: Welcome - if you're happy, please consider accepting the answer